# Is there a way to create a stereo sine signal with AudioKit that is out of phase?

Tags: audiokit

Is there an example available for AudioKit that shows how to create a left/right sine wave that is offset by a specific value (in degrees)? E.g. there is a phase shift of 90° between the two signals. I could not find it.

many thanks